Response Cache for Minimal API
We moved from old-fashioned Controllers to minimal API in our c# projects. So far so good for most view points we prefer minimal API. However one topic we can't solve: Response Caching.
In Controller based development one can add the attribute to add the response cache (important, we are talking about client side caching, not server side)
    [ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 30)]

For minimal API I found this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-8.0
But I can't understand, how I can chose which endpoints to have response cache and which one don't. I appears, all endpoints will use the same cache which is something I absolutely don't want.
My copilot proposes this here
app.MapGet("/data", () =>
{
    var response = Results.Json(new { message = "Cached Data" });
    response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=60";
    return response;
});

I can live with that, but can we combine that to something like?
app.MapGet("/data", () =>
{
    var response = new { message = "Cached Data" };
    return response;
}).UseResponseCache(60);


Hm... at least in localhost that doesn't work.

I have done some digging through Minimal APIs source code. And as a result I've created bug for ASP.NET Core - there you could find how it could work - but at this point i am not sure whether it's bug or a feature :D

I would define such extension method for RouteHandlerBuilder:
public static RouteHandlerBuilder WithResponseCache(
    this RouteHandlerBuilder builder,
    int durationSeconds,
    string varyByHeader)
{
    builder.Add(endpointBuilder =>
    {
        endpointBuilder.Metadata.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute()
        {
            Duration = durationSeconds,
            VaryByHeader = varyByHeader,
        });
    });

    return builder;
}

This unforutnately won't work out of the box with Minimal APIs, for that we need to register custom middleware (as described in the documentation) to handle the metadata:
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var endpointMetadata = context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata;

    if(endpointMetadata is not null)
    {
        var responseCache = endpointMetadata.FirstOrDefault(x => x is ResponseCacheAttribute);

        if(responseCache is ResponseCacheAttribute attribute)
        {
            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attribute.Duration)
                };
            context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                new string[] { attribute.VaryByHeader };
        }
    }

    await next();
});

Of course, you need to also call AddResponseCaching and UseResponseCaching to add needed services.
And I just used ResponseCacheAttribute class, but you could of course use also custom class for that.
